# Comma separated values from datatable using linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

[image]This is my `DataTable` structure:

```
srno. areaid areaName
1     1      Mumbai
2     1      Delhi
3     1      New York
4     2      Sydney
```

I want to query it and the result should be:

```
srno. areaid areaName
1     1      Mumbai,Delhi, New York
2     2      Sydney
```

This is my query:

```
Dim grouped = From row In a.AsEnumerable()
              Group row By id = row.Field(Of String)(areaid) Into Group
              Select id, areaName = String.Join(",", From i In Group Select i.Field(Of String)("areaName"))
```

I am getting the result:

> Results = Type expected.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Select` statement you need create instance of anonymous class

```
Dim grouped = 
    a.AsEnumerable().
      GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("areaid")).
      Select(Function(group, areaId)
                 Return New With
                 {
                     .AreaId = areaId,
                     .AreaNames = String.Join(",", group.Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("areaName")))
                 }
             End Function)
```

Comment: no bro same issue!! I just updated snap using your code

Comment: You need cast value of  "areaid" column to the `Integer`. In your code you casting it to the `String` and provide column name properly as string `"areaid"`

Comment: i dont think that is the issue. I changed it and still no success. By the way the query which i posted returned data when i removed second coloumn "areaName " from the select.
so i guess there is something wrong with select

Comment: my bad your solution worked perfectly!!! thanks a ton..
the only change i made was
.AreaId= group.Select(Function(row) row.Field(Of String)("AreaId")
and while using value i used .first

Comment: @Sameer, AreId is an key of group, so it can be accesses without `group.Select...`

Answer (score 3):

The key as Fabio points out is creating an Anon type for the return.  But the group SELECT can be skipped by acting on it in the `GroupBy` method.

```
Dim grouped = dt.AsEnumerable().
        GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of Integer)("AreaId"),
                Function(key, values) New With {
                    .Id = key,
                    .Names = String.Join(",", values.
                                      Select(Function(q) q.Field(Of String)("AreaName")))
                                               }
                ).OrderBy(Function(j) j.Id)

For Each item In grouped
    Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", item.Id, item.Names)
Next
```

I added a few more elements to the table (2 groups is not a good test) and in less ordered sequence.  The result:

> 1  Mumbai,Delhi,New York
>   2  Sydney
>   3  Paris,London